# A first chance exception of type 'Parse.ParseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

I am doing a very basic thing here. I have a parse class called "Score" where i am trying to add a new object. I have also added my application ID and .net Key in App.xaml.cs. But i keep getting this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Parse.ParseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

and it points to:

```
await gameScore.SaveAsync();
```

Here is the code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    async private void signInClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("Score");
        gameScore["score"] = 1337;
        gameScore["name"] = "Sean Plott";
        await gameScore.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this ParseException?

Comment: Do you have the inner exception at all? Is there any more information from the exception?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau no...its showing unauthorized in front of Additional Information. Although before this actual exception i get a popup saying "Source file xxx does not belong to the project being debugged"

Answer (score 0):

1. check the .net Key, App Id and Server URI as well
2. check that whether you have "Full control" in windows file or folder properties.
   [image: just in case]
3. Try to run Visual Studio as administrator.